subtract brush cannot remove weight from model in weight painting

i tried all brushes and none of them can affect this point of model, i set brush setting to max weight and strength but it still cant remove that while it still able to remove weight from every other places


hello could you please share your file (at least this part)? https://blend-exchange.com/

 here u go

Your vertex is only part of one vertex group and as the Auto Normalize option is activated it doesn't want to subtract, deactivate the option:


thanks you so much man, im very appreciate for ur help ^^
